# How do I enabel my VPN on my standard account?

Tags: sudo, vpn

I use a VPN client named MullvadVPN I have to use from time to time. I use a Standard profile for my day to day work and the problem is that the VPN client have to have Sudo access to run. And since I do not have sudo privileges this is an issue.

Is there any way to allow this program and some others to run at the Standard account and still not allow the rest? Do I have to change some settings at the Administrator account and if so, how do I do it?

Edit: It is for my home computer so I have Admin privileges on my Administrator account. Just do not like to use it other than updating and installing programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obviously did not make a lot of research for this

From https://mullvad.net/en/setup/openvpn/, you have the following procedure

- Log in
- Install network-manager-openvpn (`sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn`)
- Extract the configuration files
- Import mullvad_linux.conf using the Network Manager menu

Comment: I have read this. But I sure do feel like a complete jackass when I have to ask, how can I install network-manager-openvpn if I do not have sudo privileges?

Comment: Do I import to the standard account from the root account?

Comment: ah well sorry. if you don't have sudo privelege then you can't do anything unless the needed software is already installed. May be network-manager-openvpn islaredy installed ? I don't understand the 2nd comment.

Comment: Ahh I think I got it now. The problem I had was that I was not logged in to my account. When I logged in the extraction files apperd as a zip. Than I could download and import them. Before I got stuck at step 3 - 4 beaus I did not know what to import and extract. Thank you for the help!